# Breeze GetEntityByKey doesn't always get results back in time

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm using Breeze getEntiryByKey to query the cache and set AngularJS scope variables. The problem I'm having is that sometimes the whole page finishes loading before the results make it to the browser.

If I keep refreshing the page (by pressing F5 or ctrl-F5 multiple times), it will work most of the time showing the data as expected, but there will be times when the page loads and none of the values make it through.

I'm calling the function that queries the cache and sets the scope variables in the controller file itself so that all of this happens during the initial page load.

Since it only works sporadically, it seems like there is latency caused by something -- though it can't be the network as this function is supposed to query the local cache and return immediately.  [See getEntityByKey in the Breeze docs.](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples#queryByKey) Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using ASP.NET Web API with Breeze server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *getEntityByKey* method IS synchronous which means that it is returning immediately.  This in turn means that your issue has to do with the angular scope not refreshing in time because this is an async operation.  However, I think you can force angular to refresh by calling "$scope.$apply()" immediately after your getEntityByKey call.

Comment: I thought of that too, though I forgot to mention it.  I put $scope.$apply() at the end of the function but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the object returned by the getEntityByKey is in the $scope object when you call $apply?

Comment: It seems to be working now.  I just have to put $scope.$apply() in the right place.